# Data from google analytics to google sheets - numbers in wrong format

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I am trying to import my Google analytics numbers to google sheets using google analytics add-on. My problem is that numbers for example revenue is downloaded in US format "3212.23" and I would like to have format "3212,23".

I tried to use Importrange to import data to another google sheet, but unfortunately it did not help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to change `file>spreadsheet settings>locale` from the menu bar in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics API returns the data in the standard American format for numbers  `.` being decimal place.

Depending upon what language you have the sheet settings set to that country the default decimal format will be the one for that country.

> Google Docs to Spanish Google Docs spreadsheets will by default use
>   the Spain locale and the date/time and decimal comma used in this
>   locale.

I would think that you could do a replace of some kind on the . returning from the API on numbers.